# Create android module library from existing source

Tags: android

I want to create a module to include it on other applications.

Comment: File > new Gradle module? In any case, it's called a library only because it contains external functions and classes. Module is just Intellij terminology

Comment: there is no Gradle it's file > new > module I tried it just create a library inside the source i want to convert it to library !!

Comment: It is a library at that point. You can open another project and import that module from the build.gradle file. Do you mean actually publish something to JCenter?

Comment: no I don't mean JCenter , I tried to import it into non Gradle app but it didn't work , I'll try it on Gradle app ,thank you

Comment: At least I think it should work. I have only made a local module for my Android apps to separate out the core Java-specific stuff

Comment: You'll also need to add a `compile project` line into the module that depends on that other one

Comment: It works I can see the modules but what I should imported first time I import the whole app and it give me 2 modules the app itself and the module I created inside it , second time I imported the library only which is right ? thanks for your concern

Comment: If you only want the library, then yes, only select that Gradle file, not the one in the directory above it

Comment: alright thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new Android/Java Gradle project (depending on your needs), then if you would like to use that as a library, you can go into the project settings and import the corresponding `build.gradle` for that project/module.

You may additionally need to `compile project` in your own Gradle file to actually pull in those classes to your project.

Comment: actually it worked but I have to change in the module(lib one) build.gradle file :
remove    applicationId and change the apply plugin: 'com.android.application' to apply plugin:  'com.android.library'